# DataFrame how to perform calculations (please see the attached photo)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

[image: index calculation]

As you can see the calculations under column D follow a specific pattern 
i.e. prior value * (1+the rate%/365)

so in cell D2 you have 100*(1+8%/365)
D3 will be 100.021918*(1+8.06%/365)

is there an easy way to do that in python as I don't want to use excel for that purpose....and I have daily data going back 30 years.

Comment: `df['D']*(df['C'].shift(-1) * 365 + 1)`?

Comment: hi mate, no that doesn't seem to work. that is what I was trying for a while

Comment: Oh, so you want to build the `D` column. Check out `ewm`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
cell_d = [100]
rates = [0.08, 0.0806, 0.0812, 0.0813, 0.08]
for i, rate in enumerate(rates):
    cell_d.append(cell_d[i] * (1 + rate/365))
pd.DataFrame({'rates': rates, 'cell_d': cell_d[1:]})
```

Probably should rename `cell_d` to something more meaningful.

Comment: thanks Adrian, wanted to see if I could avoid for loop.

Comment: @PrasKam I realized that vectorizing this might be difficult since the values you need for cell_d are dependent on the prior calculation.

Comment: thanks again @adrianp, the code gives me the answer am after. only issues is am losing all the dates as its a timeseries. My new index has numerical values. if you put hypothetical dates against each rate how will you get a DataFrame with dates as well (as an index)?

Comment: @PrasKam, you can pass the dates as an index to the DataFrame constructor: `pd.DataFrame({...}, index=dates`).

Comment: actually yes I can pass that separately once I have the df ready. thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know of any "DataFrame friendly" way to do it, but you can simply iterate over the rows with an index using a for loop.

```py
for i in range(1, num_rows):
    df[i]["value"] = df[i-1]["value"] * (1 + df[i]["rate"]/365)
```

Comment: thanks @alon-k, i was ideally trying to avoid for loop and wanted to check if possible to do using "DF friendly way".